# <script></script> or <script />?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

I just found a weired behavior with the *script* tag in HTML.

I web server is nginx, and I used FAST CGI and PHP5. I have a page.html, which looks like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- <?php echo 'i am going to add php code here'; ?> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./my/javascript1.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./my/javascript2.js" />
  </body>
</html>
```

If this page is served directly from the web server, the java script works well. But if it passed to PHP5, it seems only the first java script tag is executed. But if I change the *script* block into:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./my/javascript1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./my/javascript2.js"></script>
```

Everything works again. Noticed how the tags are closed? Yeah, that is why I am asking here. What is the difference? They are supposed to have the same function/meaning. Besides, the output HTML that my web browser (Chrome/IE9) received are the same, but why treated differently?

Comment: What do you mean by "if it passed to php5" ?

Comment: Further reading : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Comment: @Nanne set a handle in Nginx so the page is processed by PHP5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The script tag needs a separate closing tag to be valid code. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1

Some browsers will accept the self closing tag, others wont, and the HTML version that you are using also affects the result. There are not self closing tags unless you use XHTML.

Passing the file through the PHP engine should not change the result, but it's possible that it makes an attempt to correct the incorrect script tags. You should view the source in the browser to see if the tags has been changed.

Comment: want to take a shot at answering this part - `If this page is served directly from the web server, the java script works well. But if it passed to PHP5`? I'm assuming he means PHP vs HTML.

Answer (score 4):

The `script` tag is required to have a closing tag, even if it uses the `src` attribute. Avoiding it causes undesired behaviours.

Answer (score 0):

The way your browser interprets your HTML has nothing to do with PHP since it is NOT an HTML parser. Some browsers accept it. others don't....  Also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work). for more Q&A about the same topic

Answer (score -1):

It appears that your server is configured to output XHTML rather than HTML.
HTML has no such things as `<tag />`. But XML does have them.

Check document type declaration in both cases. `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"` and the like at the beginning of your document.

Answer (score -3):

That is basically dependant upon your `DocType` mentioned in the `HTML`.

If the `DocType` is mentioned `transitional XHTML` then it would not allow the script tag to be closed like this `<script ... />`. It would only allow the tag to be closed like this. `<script ... ></script>` and so on.

If the `DocTYpe` is something other than `XHTML` it would depend on browser compatibility in that case.

For a reference, see this...

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: That is not correct. The closing tag is always required, regardless of the HTML version used.

Comment: The thing I mentioned above is 100% right (although not bookish), but it works with most of the browsers (including IE 6)

Comment: No browser that i know of allows `<script ... />` in HTML of any kind.  It's invalid HTML, and every browser i've ever seen treats it as equivalent to `<script ... >` with no closing tag, which causes varied-but-always-wrong behavior among different browsers.

Comment: BTW, w3schools sucks as a reference for stuff like this.

Comment: so what would you relate for a reference on stuff like this ? cHao ?

Comment: @Naveed Butt: By specifying the conditions when the selfclosed tag can't be used, the answer implies that it can be used in the other cases. It's like saying "if you have red shoes, you can't walk on water".

Comment: @Naveed: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1

Comment: @Naveed: The official specs on HTML might be a good start.  `<script />` has never been valid HTML, even in HTML5 -- and it could actually spit out unwanted chars in a fully-SGML-compliant HTML parser (though fortunately, i don't know of any in common use, and HTML5 seems to finally be breaking ties with SGML anyway).

Comment: @cHao: Opera is OK with `<script ... />` .  I've hit this issue before when generating tag soup via XSLT.